# How to arrange stacked column chart in ascending order in Excel?

Tags: excel, sorting, charts, excel-2016, stacked-chart

I have the table in Excel:
[image]

I have generated 100% stacked column chart for this data. It looks like this:
[image]

But it's not arranged. I want the stacked chart to be arranged in ascending order. Parameter is `accuracy rate (%)`. So I want green columns (accuracy rate) to be arranged in ascending order from left to right. Red columns is `error rate`. In my table data is arranged by accuracy.

For the chart Excel generated some table. I tried to sort it from smallest to largest (by `accuracy rate` paramemter), but it didn't work:
[image]

---

How can I do it in Excel?

---

*Excel file:* [*4.14 (SO).xlsx*](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qftxl7scqb2e7m1/4.14%20%28SO%29.xlsx?dl=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7hY4V8Ao1O9SFRmYXg1UTZjOVU/view?usp=docslist_api

Please follow the link.

I have used data sorting + pivot sorting, both are working fine.